# Saving and retrieving values from memory location

Tags: c, memory-management

So, If I want to save numbers on memory locations, and then retrieving them back, what can be possible ways? (It's my home work.)

Suppose I calculate sum of two numbers, save it in memory, again calculate it, again save it an so on.Now, how can I retriev them back?

I have thought about `arrays`.Save the numbers in contiguous memory locations.Thats an Easy way. But, here is a contradiction.My teacher wants me to save few results, then retriev them back, when user starts the process again, start the allocation from starting.

Again, can use arrays with a counter, but I think he wants something else like saving the numbers on the memory location like 0X1000 or something.

Is there some way out? Sorry I am a C beginner. Thank you.

Comment: If even you don't understand exactly what you're supposed to do, how can we help? Ask your teacher for clarifications, then try implementing it yourself, then come here for help if you're stuck.

Comment: If you want to persist data between runs of your program, look into using a file.  You can read up on [fopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen), [fwrite](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite) and [fread](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) if this sounds like a useful approach.

Comment: In C, storing data in memory that has not been allocated to your program is undefined behavior, so the trick with `0X1000` is certainly out of the question.

Comment: @simonc yes, good idea. But have to store it in the memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [shared memory segments](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/shm.html). They are used for inter-process communication which is precisely what you need as memory there will persist between the different invocations of your program (which are in effect various process instances of it).

You could have one process maintaining the segment and other processes attaching themselves to it and reading/writing from it.

This [link](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html) also contains explanation and plenty of examples of how to use them.

Comment: Helped me a ton.Thanks for the links !!